# What do the underlined letters in Firefox menus mean?

Tags: firefox

What do the underlined letters in Firefox menus mean?

I heard or assumed it's about shortcuts but Ctrl+theletter does not do what I would expect.

Comment: Very little information here. Can you edit your post to show a screen shot?

Comment: `Ctrl+theletter does not do what I would expect` ... what did you do? ... what were you expecting to happen? ... what did happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underlined letters in menus:

This is a "Windows"-ism, a heritage from the dark side.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the menu bar appears.
You now see e.g. "File" with an underlined F; Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to reveal the File menu.
T in "New Tab" is underlined, so <kbd>T</kbd> opens a new tab...

As many of Firefox's menus already have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>- shortcut keys, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>- key method is slightly out of place in FF.

But this is more general than so though, MOST software menus are accessible in this way, even when the underlining isn't there:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> opens Firefox's history menu, <kbd>R</kbd> will select "Restore previous session", as it is the first alternative in the menu that has an initial "R", hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate it.

*Ref: FF 94.0 on Ubuntu, if it happens to make a difference.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> 9 times, type `Keyboard Shortcuts`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> - for more.*